# SVG Misrendering Characters in some devices

Tags: html, web, svg

I have a SVG with a logo and some text (lets say : "Hitch Hike") put up on my website.

And (Only) in some android devices (Version 7 is what I have observed) Hitch Hike is show as "KitcK Kike". `H` is transforming into `K`. This definitely is not a grouping issue while exporting SVG, as it will break in all devices. And even if a SVG breaks it should show some lines not an entirely different character.

Is there any global support SVG versioning or any one know what could have caused this?

*Cannot paste SVG here due to copy right issues*.

Comment: are you using adobe illustrator?

Comment: Yes I suppose, it was designed by someone an year back in illustrator

Comment: if you have illustrator you can convert the text to outlines by selecting the text and pressing cmd + O on your keyboard. then the text will display correctly.

Comment: Yes, done in the same way and working fine in all devices except older android versions. Wanted to know why is it happening

Comment: I think it has something to do with the font file used to create the logo.

Comment: Oh, but even with the font, text should not be mis-rendering right? It was a perfect `K`

Comment: Perhaps the font had an alternate form H that the designer used.  But Android N had a bug in the code that determined which glyph to use (?).  Who knows. 
 It's impossible to say without the SVG or the font.  But the correct solution is to always convert your text to outlines. Don't rely on users devices having the correct font available.

Comment: Yes, it is solved with outlines, but am still curious on learning the cause. Will do my research and post if I find anything here.